# Issue Displaying Images When Logged Out

Tags: .net, asp.net, forms-authentication, authorization

I have two images, a header image that appears at the top, and a logo that I position within the image.  The header image is applied on a DIV with a `style="background-image(url('x'));"`, and the logo via `<asp:Image />`.  The images are in a Content folder.

In my config file, I enable permissions to anonymous users in the Content folder via:

```
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But for some reason, the header image appears but the logo image doesn't appear when the user logs out.  The logo appears when logged in.

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting authorization on the Content folder at all? You probably don't need it.